# Web Application Project not shown at Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web-applications

I'm trying to create my first Web Application Project and the icon is not appearing. Here I link a picture because for some reason I'm not available to post images (I think that it's because of my rank)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbwpG.png

Thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 0):

As it seems, looking at your screencap, the web application templates are not installed. You need to install them. If for some reason they are not installed properly try to run devenv.exe with the /installvstemplates switch. See some info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0fyc0azh(v=vs.110).aspx.

But before that, you should really consider getting the community edition of Visual Studio 2015. Newer seems better.